# Error in filtering out records for creating gauge chart in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a gauge chart which takes as input 4 variables each with 4 options and if there is/are any records in the dataframe that matches the 4 variables, the corresponding output columns will be summed and result should be displayed in gauge chart.

```
filteredData <- reactive({
    filterData <- a
    filterData <- filter(filterData, Number_of_children == input$Number_of_children)
    filterData <- filter(filterData, age_cat == input$age_cat)
    filterData <- filter(filterData, Method == input$Method)
    filterData <- filter(filterData, income_cat == input$income_cat)
    filterData


totalRevenue <- reactive({
    sum(filteredData()$Revenue)
  })
```

This is my code for filtering out the relevant records. I get the error

Warning: Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

I understand that if there is only record filtered out $ operator cannot be used. How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a minimal (!!) working shiny app and a snippet of your data or some fake data. As is we only know that your code does not work. At a first glance your code looks fine. But your code snippet does not give any information on what might be the reason for your issue and how to fix that.